# is there a way to run a method once the Fragement is visible?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity `SelectionSort.java` which contains an

- EditText input;
- EditText output;
- -button sort : once the button is clicked it sorts the input
- a button that opens another fragment `steps.java`

is there a way to run the method `selectionsortmethod` once the fragement is visible and display the output in a textview ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override onResume() and call your method from there, so it will run when your fragment will become visible.
P. S. I kindly suggest you to follow Java naming conventions - only classes should start with a capital letters, method and field names should start with lowercase.